# can I use case when for updating muti-rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Language:Java DB:MySql

---

I have 2 sorted list to update a 'table':

```
List A :
--------
a1
a2
.
.
.
a10000

list B:
--------
b1
b2
b3
...
b10000


table
---------
Column A  Column B
```

Can I use case...when? is there any performance problem (10000 records)?

```
UPDATE `table` SET `A` = CASE
    WHEN B = b1 THEN a1
    WHEN B = b2 THEN a2
    ....
    WHEN B = b10000 THEN a10000
    END
WHERE B in (b1,b2,....b10000)
```

---

Comment: You can use `CASE` in a `SET` clause, but the example you have here is confusing. Are `List A` and `List B` tables? If so, thy can probably be joined.  Please post examples of the actual input data together with a sample of what the actual output should look like.

Comment: thank you.list A and B is 2 java list<string> .

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use `case`.  I'm not sure what you mean by "performance problem".  You might start to encounter other issues if you have a query with 10,000 ids listed (MySQL can handle very large queries but there can be issues between the application and the server).

Instead, put the data in a table with two columns:  `a` and `b`.  Then do the update as:

```
update `table` t join
       ab
       on t.a = ab.a
   set t.b = ab.b;
```

With an index on `ab(a)`, this should be have good performance.

Comment: thank you, my reputations is too few to upvote your answer:(